# change thunderbird's icon while running

Tags: scripts, python, icons, thunderbird, javascript

I'm searching a way to **temporarily** change the icon of an application (thunderbird in my case) while it's running. I tried a dozen of addons, but none if them did the job. Is there a way to code this?

PS: Pidgin's IM window does it all the time, maybe we could steal their way?

Comment: Why do you want to change it while running?

Comment: @SadeghGhasemi For a simple new mail notification without anything popping up. The icon is shown in [this](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Icon+Tasks?content=144808) plasmoid…

Comment: So you want to change the popup notification? I don't see what it has to do with the applications icon.

Comment: The linked plasmoid shows the application icon (real-time, as pidgin shows), not the starter icon, and I just want it to show me when new mail arrived. I do **not** want anything to pop up, that's the important part about it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The icon you're looking for is located in a package file, named **omni.ja** located in `/usr/lib/thunderbird` or `/usr/lib/thunderbird{version}`.
After opening it go to `/chrome/classic/skin/classic/messenger/icons` .
You have to change **"new-mail-alert.png**" with a .png image with the same size (32*32).

If you just want to disable popup notification in Thunderbird go to preference and in the general tab uncheck the "Show an alert" under When new messages arrive.

Comment: Thank you for researching this, I'm thrilled you found it! Unfortunately, changeing this icon (and repacking and replacing the original, of course) doesn't change thunderbird's icon – even when I restart the program, the old icon remains. Did you try this way out?